Create a numpy table in C++
I have a C++ DLL that utilizes numpy tables created in Python.  I can add and retrieve data in C++ and Python from the table easily.
The table currently is created in Python using:
class MyTable(object):       
    _table_type = np.dtype({'names': ['field1', 'field2'],
        'formats':[np.float32, np.float32],
        'offsets':[0, 4]})
    _table_len = 42
    self._table = np.empty(MyTable.table_len, MyTable._table_type)

I would like to be able to create the table originally in C++ using a structure def, e.g.:
struct Table 
{    
    float32 field1;
    float32 field2;
}
pybind11::array_t<Table> MyTable = magic_function(length, ...(necessary Table defs here...);

and then access this from python as a numpy table or in C++ as an array of Table.
Any guidance would be welcome.

I'll defer to others who know more about the actual question, but if I'm reading this correctly, wouldn't it make more sense to name that struct Row?

Use the NumPy C api to give Python a view on your chunk of memory.

Be aware that compilers can add some padding between fields but it should be fine here AFAIK since the two fields are of the same type and their alignement is expected to be the same as their size (I wonder if the opposite might be theoretically possible).

you have to create array_t in prescribed way, because it's not a C++-native object. It's dynamic. So, example of magic function is given here https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html
